# Change multiple html5 video player speed

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, playback

I have a page with few HTML5 video players, and i want to play all of them in 0.5x speed. I have shown js snippet that runs for single video player only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* play video twice as fast */
  document.querySelector('video').defaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
  document.querySelector('video').play();

  /* now play three times as fast just for the heck of it */
  document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 3.0;
</script>
```

This works for first video only. I need it for every video. Below is a snippet of a part of html.

```
<ul class="regular slider">
    <li class="videodiv" style="background-image: url('boxing.jpg')">
      <video preload="yes" loop>
        <source src="12950321.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
      <div class="slantedcaption">Boxing</div>
      <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Boxing</h2>
          <div class="category">Passion</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="videodiv" style="background-image: url('coding.jpg')">
      <video preload="yes" loop>
        <source src="14019065.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
      <div class="slantedcaption">Boxing</div>
      <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Boxing</h2>
          <div class="category">Passion</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="videodiv" style="background-image: url('dance.jpg')">
      <video preload="yes" loop>
        <source src="12950321.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
      <div class="slantedcaption">Boxing</div>
      <a href="detail.html">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Boxing</h2>
          <div class="category">Passion</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in Javscript file as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* play video twice as fast */
  document.querySelector('video').defaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
  document.querySelector('video').play();

  /* now play three times as fast just for the heck of it */
  var videos =document.querySelectorAll('video');
  for (var i=0;i<videos.length;i++)
  {
    videos[i].playbackRate = 3.0;
  }
</script>
```

The mistake is as you use querySelector , it returns one video object.
As the querySelectorAll,returns the array of objects (as all video tag) .So you have to iterate the array and increase the speedrate of video.

Hope it may helps.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because querySelector only returns the first element.

You can use querySelectorAll instead if you want to access multiple video tags.

querySelectorAll will return an array of all your videos, then you will need to loop them to apply your defaultPlaybackRate.

Example:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

for(i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
  videos[i].playbackRate = 0.5;
}
```